# Why is my Text in center when i did not wrap it with Center Widget?

Tags: flutter, dart

I am trying to figure out why my Text appears in the top Center of the container when i did not used the Center Widget as the parent widget for Text...

```
          Card(
        child: InkWell(
          child: Container(
              color: Colors.grey[700],
              width: 380,
              height: 100,
              child: Column(children: [
                Padding(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 6),
                ),
                Text(
                  '16:00 - 18:00',
                  style: TextStyle(
                      fontFamily: 'Spartan',
                      fontSize: 30,
                      color: Colors.yellow[600]),
                ),
              ])),
        ),
        elevation: 2.0,
      )
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Column widget has alignment on his own. Try changing it's `crossAxisAlignment` property to `.start` to align the Text to the left, or `.end` to do it to the right

```
Column(
...
    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
...
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Im scratching my head alot because of this.. i might go bald haha, anyways i checked the docs for it but i dont understand those axis stuffs, thanks for clearing it up !